# Identifying if a $ S $ given is a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Could you help me to identify if $ S $ is a vector subspace?

I started learning linear algebra and I get this question and I am lost.

[image]

Comment: I know that I have to prove the addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Ok if you take $f$ and $g$ in $S$ $\int_0^1 (f(x)+g(x))^2 dx$ is zero?

Comment: I tried http://alojaimagens.com/images/2anua78yip4i8954h9g.jpg .

Comment: Um. So are these $f$ allowed to take complex values? Because otherwise $f(x)^2$ is a positive continuous function with $0$ integral...

Comment: no, these f are not allowed to take complex values.

Comment: So think about what @JHance wrote. What does it tell you about a continuous real-valued function $f$, if $\int_0^1f^2=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Given $\lambda \in \Bbb R$, and $f,g \in S $, that is, we have $$\int_0^1 (f(x))^2 \ \mathrm{d}x = 0 \quad \mbox{and} \quad \int_0^1 (g(x))^2\ \mathrm{d}x = 0$$
try to prove that: $$\int_0^1 (f(x) + \lambda g(x))^2 \ \mathrm{d}x = 0$$
or disprove it, finding specific $f, g$ and $\lambda$ for which it fails. Proving this integral is an attempt to prove that: $$\lambda \in \Bbb R, \ f,g \in S \implies f+\lambda g\in S $$
This is just saying that $S$ is closed under the operations of sum and product by scalar.

Comment: I tried http://alojaimagens.com/images/2anua78yip4i8954h9g.jpg .